# Vb.Net Get Report Name from String

Tags: string, vb.net, class, crystal-reports

I have different Crystal Reports in my project like:

RptHbl
RptUBL
RptMCB
RptBAF

and so on...

Now I have a string with one of the report name which it gets from database
Like:

Dim Myrptname = "RptHbl"

Now I want to load a Report, for which i usually use the following code to initialize the report

Dim Myrpt As New RptHbl

Now how I can use a report name which is stored in string Myrptname
Like
Dim Myrpt as New "MyrptName"???????
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need the full name of the report class, so if the name in the database is just the class name, you'll need to append the namespace:

```
Dim reportName As String = "RptHbl"
Dim fullTypeName As String = "MyNamespace." & reportName ' Consider using the NameOf operator
```

Next, you can use `Assembly.GetType` which uses reflection to find the type (i.e. the class) by the full name.  However, first you need to get a reference to the right assembly.  If your reports are in the same assembly, you can do it like this:

```
Dim reportAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
Dim reportType As Type = reportAssembly.GetType(fullTypeName)
```

However, if the reports are in a different assembly, then, as long as you have a reference to one of them, you could do it like this:

```
Dim reportAssembly As Assembly = GetType(RptHbl).Assembly
Dim reportType As Type = reportAssembly.GetType(fullTypeName)
```

Once you have that `Type` object that describes the report class, you can create an instance of it using the `Activator.CreateInstance` method, like this:

```
Dim report As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(reportType)
```

I don't know enough about Crystal Reports to know, but I would assume that all report classes are derived from some base class.  For the sake of example, let's just assume that they all inherit from a base class called `Report`.  If so, then you can cast the new instance to that base type, like this:

```
Dim report As Report = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(reportType), Report)
```

So, to put it all together, you could do something along these lines:

```
Function CreateReport(name As String) As Report
    Dim reportTypeName As String = "MyNamespace." & name
    Dim reportAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
    Dim reportType As Type = reportAssembly.GetType(reportTypeName)
    Return DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(reportType), Report)
End Function
```